# Vectorizing Pandas datetime rollbacks/merging on dataframe from API

Tags: python, pandas

I read in a dataset with datetimtes:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(
    (file,
    parse_dates=['Take_Date'],
    infer_datetime_format=True,
    low_memory=False)
```

It works fine.  The Take_Date column is of particular interest.

I want to put everything in UTC:

```
dt = pd.DatetimeIndex(data=data['Take_Date'], tz='US/Eastern')
dt = dt.tz_convert(tz='UTC')
```

No problem.  Now I am going to use this dataframe to merge onto a third party data source via API calls.  The last available dates for each variable are different.  So let's say a variable I want to merge on has last updates each last Saturday.  To get a key to merge on, I want to use the pandas datetime offset and rollback feature.  So, I try like this:

```
dt = pd.offsets.Week(weekday=5).rollback(dt)
```

This results in:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert input [DatetimeIndex(['2018-03-30 05:49:48.713000+00:00',
           ...],
          dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='Take_Date', length=80243, freq=None)] of type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> to Timestamp
```

I realize the vector I generated is not a column in the df yet.  It works fine with individual timestamps, but I don't want to loop over the entire dataframe rows.  Is there a more efficient way to handle this?

Comment: It looks like you want to write `dt = dt.tz_convert(tz='UTC').map(pd.offsets.Week(weekday=5).rollback)`, and pandas will handle it in the most efficient way it can, since it's not a vectorized function.

Comment: @P Maschhoff - thank you!